# Compute the variance of a function of a random variable

Tags: self-study, variance, random-variable, expected-value

I don't get the solution of an exercise. The exercises is this:

> Let $Y$ be a normal random variable with mean 3 and variance 16. Let
> $V=\frac{4-Y}{3}$. Find $Var(V)$

I got $E[Y]=3$, $E[V]=1/3$, but I don't see how to compute the variance. Specifically:

$Var(V) = E[V^{2}]-E[V]^{2}$

$Var(V) = E[V^{2}]-(\frac{1}{3})^{2}$

$E[V^{2}]=E[\frac{(4-Y)^{2}}{9}]=E[\frac{16-8Y+Y^{2}}{9}] = \frac{16-8E[Y]+E[Y^{2}]}{9}$

$E[Y^{2}]=?$

I thought that the square of $Y^{2}=Z$ would imply that the mean of $Z$ is the mean of $Y$ squared. However, it doesn't make sense as the $Z$ random variable would be nonnegative.

The solution says specifically:

[image]

Where does $\frac{1}{3^{2}}Var(16)$ come from? I don't see how can I go there from where I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are asked to calculate the expected value and variance of the linear-affine transformation:
$$
V=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}Y
$$
In general, it holds that for $Y=a+bX$
$$
E(Y)=E(a+bX)=a+bE(X)
$$
and
$$
V(Y)=V(a+bX)=b^2V(X)
$$
assuming that the first two moments exist.
Thus:
$$
E(V)=E\left(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}Y\right)=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}E(X)=\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}3=\frac{1}{3}
$$
$$
V(V)=\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2V(Y)=\frac{1}{3^2}16=\frac{16}{9}
$$

**Edit:**

Why does $V(Y)=b^2V(X)$? Keep in mind that the variance of a random variable is defined as:
$$
V(X)=E([X-E(X)]^2)
$$
Thus, if we have $Y=a+bX$, then:
\begin{align}
V(Y)&=E([Y-E(Y)]^2)\\
&=E([a+bX-E(a+bX)]^2)\\
&=E([a+bX-a-bE(X)]^2)\\
&=E([bX-bE(X)]^2)\\
&=E(b^2[X-E(X)]^2)\\
&=b^2E([X-E(X)]^2)\\
&=b^2V(X)
\end{align}

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail in the $V(Y)$ line? As I still don't understand how $Var(Y)=Var(Y) * (\frac{1}{3})^2$

Comment: That was a typo, it should read $V(Z)=V(Y)\frac{1}{3^2}$.

Comment: in words: adding a constant doesn't change the variance. multiplying by a constant k, scales the variance by k^2.

Comment: @Chris I edited my answer, I hope it now answers your question.

Comment: I figured it out! I understand that property, but this detail I was referring to: $Var(V)=Var(\frac{4-Y}{3})=Var(\frac{4}{3}-\frac{1}{3}Y)=\frac{1}{9}Var(Y)=\frac{1}{9}16=\frac{16}{9}$. If you add it to your answer I think it will be clearer. Thanks!